# some unexpected result when I code Countif formula with python Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl, countif

I am doing a project to input dates in openpyxl. I don't want to input formula in excel cell. I wrote codes as followed.

```
merged_excel_file = "D:/사업/발주 및 정산/정산/정산서/"+ txt_file.get() + ".xlsx"

total_df.to_excel(merged_excel_file, sheet_name = "Sheet1", index=False)

wb = load_workbook(merged_excel_file)
ws = wb.active

last_row = ws.max_row

for o in range(5, last_row + 4):
    if f"=if(countif($B$5:B{o},B{o})" == 1:
        ws.cell(row=o, column=17).value =3000
```

When I wrote code, I expected that 3000 is written in the cell of Q column. But the result to run this code is blank. Nothing is input in the cell of Q column. I tried to solve this matter for a long time, but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: The if statement makes no sense and will always be false. PS You'll find life a lot easier if you use `ws.iter_rows(min_row=5, min_col=17, max_col=17, max_row=ws.max_row+3)`

Comment: Yes, I think if statement doesn't make any result. It was seen the first that ws. iner_rows statement. next I don't now how to do it. 
    for o in ws.iter_rows(min_row=5, min_col=17, max_row=ws.max_row+3, max_col=17):

Comment: The if statement compares two strings that will never be equal: openpyxl never evaluates formulae and even if it, this would still never work.

Comment: Okay I see that if statement doesn't work. The result that I am expecting is if there is duplicates value in B cell, Q column cell has Only one time '3000'. if not, Q column cell has also 3,000. How can I make codes without if statment?